# I try to instantiate a new instance of clsSacarioSymbols in module Main(). As I step through main() the line 1 will Not execute. It is skipped over

Tags: excel, vba

''''

```
Sub Main()
1.  Dim obLibrary As New clsSacarioSymbols
  Call CreateSacarioSymbol
End Sub
Sub CreateSacarioSymbol()
  Dim SymbolEditor  As Worksheet
  Dim MsoShapes As Shapes
  Dim SacarioGroup As Object
  Dim SacarioGroupShapes As GroupShapes
  Dim Index As Integer
  Set SymbolEditor = Sheets("Symbol Editor")
  Set MsoShapes = SymbolEditor.Shapes

  '...This Block is for testing and replicates Engineer input to SymbolEditor
  Dim ThisShape As Variant
  For Each ThisShape In SymbolEditor.Shapes
    ThisShape.Delete
  Next ThisShape
  SymbolEditor.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 310.5, 30.75, 129, 99).Select
  SymbolEditor.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 285.75, 99, 174, 61.5).Select
  '....End Testing Block

MsoShapes.SelectAll
If TypeName(Selection) = "DrawingObjects" Then
    Set SacarioGroup = Selection.Group
    Set SacarioGroupShapes = SacarioGroup.ShapeRange.GroupItems
    Dim SacarioSymbol As New clsSacarioSymbol
    SacarioSymbol.InitalizeClass SacarioGroupShapes
End If

End Sub

Class SacarioSymbol "Definition"
Private Sub class_initialize()
   ' MsgBox "Symbol Class Here"
End Sub
Public Sub InitalizeClass(SacarioSymbol As GroupShapes)
   Dim obfrmGetSymbolName As New frmGetSymbolName
   obfrmGetSymbolName.Show    
   SymbolName = obfrmGetSymbolName.GetSymbolName
   obLibrary.addSymbol Me
End Sub
Class SacarioSymbol "End Definition"
Class SacarioSymbols "Definition"
Private SacarioSymbolLibrary
Private Sub class_initialize()
   MsgBox "Sacario Library here"
  Dim SacarioSymbol As Collection
End Sub
Public Sub addSymbol(symbol As Variant)
  SacarioSymbolLibrary.add symbol
End Sub
```

Class SacarioSymbols "End Definition"

As I step through main() the line "Dim obLibrary As New clsSacarioSymbols" will not execute!
The yellow instruction line passes over this line of code.

Any direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Line 1 is a `Dim`, so it is compiled, not executed.

Comment: I modified main() by removing the original Dim and replaced it with                          
 Dim obLibrary As Variant
 Set obLibrary = New clsSacarioSymbols